# Yii client side validation doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, yii

There is a page with a link inside the "body" tag.
When the link is inserted the following view is rendered in fancybox.

```
<div class="form">
    <?php
                $model = new User;
        $model->scenario='registration';
        $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'signup-form',
                'action'=>'/signup/',
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        ),
    )); ?>

        <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
        </div>


        <div class="row buttons">
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('sign up',array('name'=>'submit')); ?>
        </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
    </div><!-- form -->
```

When the above code is inserted without fancybox the client validation script is inserted correctly, but when in fancybox there are no jQuery validation functions inserted to the page.
What can be the problem?
(siteController code is inserted here on purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely how you send the HTML to Fancybox.  If you do a renderPartial (as alluded to by user1248203), you need to make sure you have renderPartial postprocess the view that is sent back (post-processing includes javascript/css files that you want rendered along with the view itself).

More info on the [CController page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail)

One other thing to note: when you do the post-processing, you will need to make sure that the Javascript for your Fancybox (and possibly jQuery, etc) isn't sent back again.  It can cause some really confusing problems.  To keep the files from being re-sent over Ajax, use this:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = false;
Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery-ui.min.js'] = false;
etc.
```

Also note that jquery.js is sent when you're debugging on a dev server (with YII_DEBUG set to true), but jquery.min.js is sent on production servers (where YII_DEBUG is set to false).  That's bitten me :-)  You can see it defined in [framework/web/js/packages.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/js/packages.php)

Comment: you are right: renderPartial postprocess was not set (and the default value is false)

Answer (score 0):

Is the code called from an Ajax call (renderPartial) or is it called direct? Ajax calls (renderPartial) do **not** include the javascript validation function, only the whole page does.